# Polymer array push gives error

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've used `this.push` in Polymer but now I got error and I can't find what it is due to.
Here's my code:

```html
if (!ui.validation.validateForm(this.$.partnerForm)) return;

var partner = {
name: this.$.partnerName.value,
description: this.$.partnerDescription.value
};

if (!this.eventData.partners) this.eventData.partners = [];

this.push('eventData.partners', partner);
```

The error is:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HTMLTemplateElement._applySplicesArrayOrder (polymer.html:4991)
    at HTMLTemplateElement._render (polymer.html:4842)
    at Debouncer.complete (polymer-mini.html:2081)
    at Debouncer.boundComplete (polymer-mini.html:2058)
    at Object._atEndOfMicrotask (polymer-mini.html:2036)
    at MutationObserver.window.MutationObserver.observe.characterData
```

When I debug using `console.log(this.eventData.partners)` data is there, but after that it gives that error. What might be wrong with this push? Thanks.

Comment: so you want to push a string or the data value? why you are using single quotes 'eventData.partners'?

Comment: Because this is Polymer and this is its syntax. I want to push an object into `eventdata.partners` array.

Comment: You only need to use `this.push()` if you have a data binding/observer on `eventData.partners` or an observer on `eventData.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I have been used this:

`if (!this.eventData.partners) this.eventData.partners = [];`

I changed it in the following way and it's working now:

`if (!this.eventData.partners) this.set('eventData.partners', []);`

This is Polymer specific issue.